# FreeRadius - Fallthrough to next Active Directory In Post-Auth Reject

Tags: freeradius

I'm trying to explore if I can make FreeRadius fallthrough to Next Active Directory for ntlm_auth.
In other words, In Post-Auth-Type REJECT, is it possible to re-enter authenticate/authorize section and modify the Post-Auth-Type response to OK if 2nd authentication passes?

Comment: No, it's not possible, and the solution by Wang Gang won't work either.  It might be possible in FreeRADIUS v4, but there's definitely not code in there to do this now, and it'd require a lot of head scratching.

Comment: Yeah Wang's solution doesn't work for me. I'm trying to use ntlm_auth against AD and not LDAP. I could invoke ntlm_auth and pass a specific domain, but I don't have a control yet to retry authentication if auth fails against one AD. Redundant is not available in this scenario.

Comment: Arran, Do you know if there's any work goiing in FreeRADIUS v4 on this use case? I'm thinking of hacking the authenticate flow to call recursively with a different domain whenever auth fails until no more AD servers to check against.

Comment: Have you tried configuring this in samba and using rlm_winbind? If you could get samba to handle the failover then that'd be easiest.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? i can't use DNS based fail-over if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I haven't done any complex samba setups myself.

Answer (score 0):

FreeRADIUS has the redundant statement for the fall through case.

```
authenticate {
    redundant {
        [try-first]
        [try-second-if-first-failed]
    }
}
```